# Process Builder to Update formula field

Tags: process-builder, formula-field, picklist

I want to set a formula field to update when picklist value changes using process builder. How can I do so

Comment: Your question is unclear. When the field referred in the formula field value changes the formula field will update automatically. There is no need to update the formula field.

Comment: You can consider making your Process Builder "Recursive" and then tweak the logic so that it re-runs itself and would have updated formula fields on that next recursive run

Comment: Can you please add what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

A formula field value does not exist in the database - it is  calculated at the time it is queried. You can, however, request an already queried formula on an already queried object to be re-calculated using:

- [SObject.recalculateFormulas](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm)
- [Formula.recalculateFormulas](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Formula.htm)

Watch out for SOQL limit usage. From my perspective, use of the Formula class method is preferred since it specifically states the SOQL usage/limits are unaffected as long as the SObject contains values for all fields that are required by the formulas on the SObject(s) passed to it.

In order to leverage this in a Process Builder it seems likely you would have to write an [InvocableMethod](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_InvocableMethod.htm). The problem I would see is controlling the loading of necessary fields and returning the updated SObject back to the process builder since the process builder has its own contextual SObject(s). You may need to switch from Process Builder to use of flows in order to have enough control over the data, and at worst case use an apex trigger.